# How to continue to next item instead of stopping at undefined in forEach

Tags: jquery, json, foreach

I am generating multiple divs using a forEach function from json data. When there were only a few test items in my json data, it worked fine. Now that the json is up to 50+ itemsets, zero is undefined which cancels the function. Any of the `+e.portal.fields[0].xxxx+` cause it. I removed `+e.portal.fields[0].xxxx+` one by one to try to determine if it was a field that was the problem but I had to remove all reference to `fields[0]` to get the function to finish. Note that reference to `fields[1]` works fine.

```
var lists = "";
dataJ.items.forEach(function(e){
var jobcard = '<article id="listing_'+e.adId+'" attrlocation="'+e.portal.fields[1].valueId+'" title="'+e.title+'" class="col-12 mb-3 all_i all_r all_l '+e.portal.fields[0].valueId+' '+e.portal.fields[0].fields[0].valueId+' '+e.portal.fields[1].value+'  '+e.portal.fields[1].valueId+'"><div class="container article align-items-stretch bg-white"><div class="row no-gutters"><div class="col-lg-10 col-sm-12 job-detail-contents bg-white p-3"><div class="row"><div class="col-lg-7 col-sm-12 job-title text-capitalize"><h2>'+e.title+'</h2></div><div class="col-lg-5 col-sm-12 job-mini-details time-stmp">posted&nbsp;<time class="timeago" datetime="'+e.postedAt+'"> '+e.postedAt+'</time></div></div><div class="row" ><div class="col-lg-7 col-xs-4"><span style="color: #0c53a0; font-size: .85em; font-weight: 600; padding-right: 10px;text-transform: uppercase; letter-spacing: .12em;">Summary:</span><p class="job-details job_spec_summary" style="font-size: .85em;">'+e.summary+'</p></div><div class="col-lg-5 col-xs-8 job-mini-details"><div class="row"><div class="col-12"><i class="fa fa-map-marker-alt fa-sm pr-1 job_spec" style="margin-top: -.1em; color: #0c53a0;"></i><span>'+e.portal.fields[1].value+'</span></div><div class="col-12"><i class="fas fa-address-card pr-1" style="color: #0c53a0;"></i><span>'+e.portal.fields[0].value+'</span></div><div class="col-12"><i class="fas fa-building pr-1" style="color: #0c53a0;"></i><span>'+e.portal.fields[0].fields[0].value+'</span></div></div></div></div></div><div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-12 bg-transparent mb-sm-2 text-right"><button id="link-to-'+e.adId+'" href="#details-'+e.adId+'" class="btn btn-primary animated p-3 mt-5 mb-5 mr-1 changing-btn" data-hover="Check it Out" data-active="Please Wait..."><span class="d-inline-block text-white text-uppercase font-weight-bold pl-2"><i class="far fa-eye fa-lg text-white d-inline-block pr-2 "></i>details</span></button></div></div></div></article>';
lists+=jobcard;
});
$('#flatdiv').append(lists);
```

Here's the layout of the json:

```
    {  
   adId:75480,
   title:"some title",
   reference:"219109",
   summary:"some summary",
   bulletPoints:[  
      "something",
      "something",
      "something"
   ],
   portal:{  
      fields:[  
         {  
            fieldId:something,
            fieldName:"something",
            valueId:something,
            value:"something",
            fields:[  
               {  
                  fieldId:something,
                  fieldName:"something",
                  valueId:something,
                  value:"something"
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            fieldId:something,
            fieldName:"something",
            valueId:something,
            value:"something"
         },
         {  
            fieldId:something,
            fieldName:"something",
            valueId:something,
            value:"something"
         }
      ]
   },
   description:"something"
},
....
```

It's possible that one of the itemsets simply doesn't have that fields, but scouring the pages and pages of json data to find which one seems to be a pain and I haven't been able to spot the problem itemset.

What can I do to my code to simply skip the one that is causing the error and continue on to the next div that needs to be created?

UPDATED:

```
dataJ.items.forEach(function(e){

if ($(e.portal.fields[0].fields[0].valueId).length > 0){
    var jobcard = '<article id="listing_'+e.adId+'" attrlocation="'+e.portal.fields[1].valueId+'" title="'+e.title+'" class="col-12 mb-3 all_i all_r all_l '+e.portal.fields[0].valueId+' '+e.portal.fields[0].fields[0].valueId+' '+e.portal.fields[1].value+'  '+e.portal.fields[1].valueId+'"><div class="container article align-items-stretch bg-white"><div class="row no-gutters"><div class="col-lg-10 col-sm-12 job-detail-contents bg-white p-3"><div class="row"><div class="col-lg-7 col-sm-12 job-title text-capitalize"><h2>'+e.title+'</h2></div><div class="col-lg-5 col-sm-12 job-mini-details time-stmp">posted&nbsp;<time class="timeago" datetime="'+e.postedAt+'"> '+e.postedAt+'</time></div></div><div class="row" ><div class="col-lg-7 col-xs-4"><span style="color: #0c53a0; font-size: .85em; font-weight: 600; padding-right: 10px;text-transform: uppercase; letter-spacing: .12em;">Summary:</span><p class="job-details job_spec_summary" style="font-size: .85em;">'+e.summary+'</p></div><div class="col-lg-5 col-xs-8 job-mini-details"><div class="row"><div class="col-12"><i class="fa fa-map-marker-alt fa-sm pr-1 job_spec" style="margin-top: -.1em; color: #0c53a0;"></i><span>'+e.portal.fields[1].value+'</span></div><div class="col-12"><i class="fas fa-address-card pr-1" style="color: #0c53a0;"></i><span>'+e.portal.fields[0].value+'</span></div><div class="col-12"><i class="fas fa-building pr-1" style="color: #0c53a0;"></i><span>'+e.portal.fields[0].fields[0].value+'</span></div></div></div></div></div><div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-12 bg-transparent mb-sm-2 text-right"><button id="link-to-'+e.adId+'" href="#details-'+e.adId+'" class="btn btn-primary animated p-3 mt-5 mb-5 mr-1 changing-btn" data-hover="Check it Out" data-active="Please Wait..."><span class="d-inline-block text-white text-uppercase font-weight-bold pl-2"><i class="far fa-eye fa-lg text-white d-inline-block pr-2 "></i>details</span></button></div></div></div></article>';
    console.log(e.adId);                
} else {
return
};
```

Comment: `fields`, from your example, is an array.  If there is an element in position 1, there must be an element in position 0.  That element could be `null` or `undefined` or something unexpected, but it will exist.

Comment: Try checking if the data in the `forEach` "e" (`adId`, `portal.fields[1].valueId ` or whatever is required) exists before doing the loop, if that data is `null` or `undefined` just continue the loop.

Comment: @taplar i know the field exists, which is why i'm so confused as to why it kicks out an error.

Comment: @JimmyAdaro, can you provide an example of how I might implement your suggestion to my existing code? I'm novice at best.

Comment: @BridgetMcCarthy So have you tried to add a console.log of the fields[0] to see what it is at the time that you get the error?

Comment: @Taplar Hadn't thought of that...trying now.

Comment: @Taplar, okay, it was able to get through to the 7th item then kicked the error. For this item, that field does not in fact exist for the 8th json item. Can you suggest (with an example) how to say "hey, if it doesn't exist, just skip that part and keep going" but in code-y language. :)

Comment: Sounds like an `if` statement to me.

Comment: @BridgetMcCarthy As Taplar says it's just an `if` statement: check the data of item _before_ appending that string to your variable `jobcard`.

Comment: Please see my updated code above. It now kicking the error on the if line. Is my syntax wrong?

Comment: @JimmyAdaro, can you help me with the code that you suggested back on May 7th. For example, I'd like it to perform as follows: If field_x doesn't exist, make it equal to " " (a blank). That way we can "make" the field exist. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

The edited code above resolved this problem.